# generate an array of item consist of 3 different "sub-arrays"

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have a class:

```
class All{
 A a;
 B b;
 C c;
}
```

Now I get 3 arrays:

```
A[] as;
B[] bs;
C[] cs;
```

Each one of them can be empty (length=0) or null.
I need to create a list of Alls objects consists on the arrays where there is at least one element (I don't need the empty object).

```
For example:
    A[] as={a1, a2};
    B[] bs{};
    C[] cs{c1, c2};
 => Result: All[] = {
      All{a: a1, b:null, c:null},
      All{a: a1, b:null, c:c1},
      All{a: a1, b:null, c:c2},
      All{a: a2, b:null, c:null},
      All{a: a2, b:null, c:c1},
      All{a: a2, b:null, c:c2}
      All{a: null, b:null, c:c1},
      All{a: null, b:null, c:c2}
      //All{a: null, b:null, c:null} -> This is an empty object and I don't need it
};
```

How can I generate the All[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this definition of `Alls`:

```
class All
{
    public A A { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
    public C C { get; set; }
}
```

Something like this should work:

```
A[] myAs = new [] { new A(), new A(), new A()};
B[] myBs = new B[] {};
C[] myCs = new [] {new C(), new C()};

var combinations = (from a in myAs.Concat(new A[] { null })
                    from b in myBs.Concat(new B[] { null })
                    from c in myCs.Concat(new C[] { null })
                    where (!(a == null && b == null && c == null))
                    select new All() { A = a, B = b, C = c }).ToArray();
```

Comment: This doesn't included null in the combination?

Comment: @manojlds: it does include combinations where at most any two from a,b,c are null, but not all three are null.

Comment: See my answer. He is expecting a `null` to be a part of the elements to be taken in the combination.

Comment: @manojlds: that's just a matter of what you put into the A, B, C arrays but it doesn't change the solution

Comment: How? For example yours will produce {a1,b1,c1} {a1,b1,c2} etc..but never {a1,null,c2} or {a1,null,null} etc unless any of a or b or c is empty.

Comment: Atleast that's what his example shows :)  Requiring extra null

Comment: aah overlooked that part, fixed my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?  ( you might have to polish a bit though)

```
List<A> awithnull = as.ToList();
List<B> bwithnull = bs.ToList();
List<C> cwithnull = cs.ToList();

awithnull.Add(null);
bwithnull.Add(null);
cwithnull.Add(null);

var result = from ae in awithnull
             from be in bwithnull
             from ce in cwithnull
             where (!(ae==null && be ==null && ce == null))
             select new All() {a = ae, b = be, c = ce};
```

Comment: Thanks! If I could - I would take your both answers. But BrokenGlass was the first. +1

Answer (score -1):

use object declare:

```
Object[] All;
```

You can insert any objects including all the classes you have created.

Comment: I believe you don't understand my question. All consist from A, B and C and I want to create array of Alls that contains any possibility of A,B and C.